# Not able to create "Asp.Net Core Web application" in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am not able to create "Asp.Net Core Web application" in Visual Studio 2017. When I select the option to create a "Asp.Net Core Web application" I am not getting any templates in the Listbox to create the application? I even installed .Net Core 2.0 and rebooted my system. Still nothing is getting loaded to proceed?

Any ideas what is it I am missing here?
[image][image]
Note: 2 times I have uninstalled it and Installed .Net core 2.0 and Visual Studio 2017 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is I need to download the installer from the url ( https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core )

Here is an issue which report that the installers downloaded from different source may lead to different results after installing them. Please take it as reference.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/961